# How can I natively load docker secrets mounted as a volume in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-volume, kubernetes-secrets, docker-secrets

How can my spring boot application running inside a container access docker secrets [mounted as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#how-docker-manages-secrets) inside that same container?

Commonly suggested methods **I DO NOT** want to use:

- Echo the secret into an environment variable - this is insecure.
- Pass the secret in as a command line argument - this is messy with multiple secrets and hurts the local dev experience
- Manually read the secret from a file by implementing my own property loader - Spring must have a native way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring boot 2.4 introduced this feature as part of [Volume mounted config trees](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#volume-mounted-configuration-trees) using the `spring.config.import` property.
To read docker secrets mounted as a volume from the default location set:

```
spring.config.import = configtree:/run/secrets/
```

The property name will be derived from the secret filename and the value from the file contents.
This can then be accessed like any other spring property.